# Program slower with multi-threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I started learning programming with multi-threads and i have program. My program is slower with multi-threads:
multi-threads: ~ 8.5 sec
without multi-threads: ~ 4.96
Someone can explain me what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
long long even_sum = 0;
long long odd_sum = 0;
void findEvenNumber(int start, int end){
    for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            even_sum++;
        }
    }
}
void findOddNumber(int start, int end){
    for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
        if(i%2==1){
            odd_sum++;
        }
    }
}
void multiTask(){
    thread t1(findEvenNumber,1,1000000000);
    thread t2(findOddNumber,1,1000000000);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
void noMultiTask(){
    findEvenNumber(1,1000000000);
    findOddNumber(1,1000000000);
}
int main(){
    clock_t start = clock();
    //noMultiTask();
    //multiTask();
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout<<(double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;


    cout<<even_sum<<" "<<odd_sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just to be sure: You ARE working on a multicore system, are you?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: `1000000000` is you int 64 bits or larger? On msvc int is 32 bit even for x64.

Comment: `cout<<(double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;`  you may want to use the chrono library for timing.

Comment: A multithreaded solution that is slower does not mean anything is wrong.  It simply means the multithreaded solution is slower.

Comment: Multithreading isn’t a magic bullet to faster code. There is a good breakdown of how to conceptualize work that can and can’t split in intro to algorithms

Comment: After changing the `int`s to `int64_t` both versions of code take pretty much the same amount of time for me in visual studio

Comment: On my Mac Mini, the non-threaded version takes 1.16 seconds, while the multi-threaded version takes 0.95 seconds.  If I modify the two functions to increment a local stack-variable instead of the global variable (and then set the global variable just once at the end of the function), that gets further reduced to 0.52 seconds, presumably by avoiding false cache-line-sharing between the two threads.  Note that I compiled with `g++ -O3 -std=c++17 ./temp.cpp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At minimum, you have a false sharing problem.  `even_count` and `odd_count` are almost certainly on the same cache line, which means when you want to touch one variable you're actually forcing the other thread to have its cacheline invalidated.  There's more to false sharing than this, but for a quick overview there's a great talk by Scott Meyers that hits on it at the start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE

By using local variables for odd/even count and only updating the globals at the end of the thread, I get much better performance on my system (1.23299 seconds vs 1.07338).

```
void findEvenNumber(int start, int end){
    auto count = 0;
    for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    even_sum += count;
}
void findOddNumber(int start, int end){
    auto count = 0;
    for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
        if(i%2==1){
            count++;
        }
    }
    odd_sum += count;
```

Comment: I've experimented a bit (e.g. added huge static array between `even_count` and `odd_count`) and it seems this is the correct explanation.

Comment: @freakish That's pure coincidence. The order of static objects in memory is unspecified. Using local variables is the right fix.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow it is unspecified by the standard. Which doesn't mean that compilers produce random ordering. In fact every sane compiler will produce the expected order. This is not a coincidence.

Comment: @freakish I'm pretty sure gcc and clang will not when the linker script sorts the .data section objects by size (or alignment). It might work today but when you add a bunch more static or global members suddenly the sort order changes. Adding an array between the 2 variables is not a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The multi-threaded version has to launch threads and wait for them to complete. The non-multi-threaded version doesn't. So it makes sense that the multi-threaded version would take more CPU time.

The multi-threaded version does take less wall time.

Comment: Okey so why this program is faster with thread: 
https://ideone.com/TXOPmc

Comment: I know there is large overhead of launching threads compared to ordinary calls but if OP correctly reports run-time over 5 seconds, the overhead should be negligible.